# Enhanced paging for asp:gridview anyone know of some solutions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm really bummed with what comes out of the box with asp:gridview pager options:
 - NextPrevious
 - NextPreviousFirstLast
 - Numeric
 - NumericFirstLast

I'm dealing with a gridview that for practical purposes really shouldn't be deeper that 10 rows at a time for good management. However, in doing that without any filtering of the source reference table this means that we are dealing with 396 pages of 10 rows each to cover the content of the table in the pager.  This simply isn't practical navigation for a device such as the default below or my original objective shown here.

[image]

But the more I thought about it even this would be laborious to trudge through 396 pages of data.  What would be better would be some kind of slider or other mechanism.

So I wanted to kick this out here and see if anyone had a solution to either enhance the default pager or replace it to provide a better means of addressing a large volume of data like I'm dealing with here.

Thoughts?

Comment: If GridView control isn't meeting your needs, then find something that does. A web search for table/grid tools implemented with JavaScript and CSS is likely to find a lot of useful things. Then there's the ones that are specific enough to ASP.NET that are easy to find to. Do a little research!

Comment: Well the pager is the only part that I'm not real thrilled with.  The rest of it I'm very happy with.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pager yourself.

There are 2 ways I can think of. The first is create your own pager on the `OnRowCreated` event of the GridView. There you can cast the `Table` of the pager and rebuild it as you see fit. I use this to add a `View all` link to the page numbers.

The second option is a client side solution with JavaScript. And this is a snippet for it. The trick is that a Pager item is nothing more than a link with javascript that look like this.

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$mainContentPane$GridView1','Page$14&')">14</a>
```

You can use that information to recreate a new link somewhere else.

The first thing is setting  the `PagerSettings-PageButtonCount` to make sure that it includes all the possible pager numbers on the page, otherwise you'll could get an `invalid postback or callback argument`

Then give the pager a CSS class with `PagerStyle-CssClass`.

The GridView Control now looks something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" PagerStyle-CssClass="gridPager" PagerSettings-PageButtonCount="100" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
```

And add this to the .aspx page

```
<style>
    /* hides the original pager */
    .gridPager {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //get the gridview name
        var gridViewName = "<%= GridView1.UniqueID %>";

        //get the current page number
        var currentPage = <%= GridView1.PageIndex + 1 %>;

        //loop some custom page count
        for (var i = 5; i <= 10; i++) {
            //add the new pager links to the customPager div
            if (i == currentPage) {
                document.getElementById('customPager').innerHTML += i + "<br>";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('customPager').innerHTML += '<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(\'' + gridViewName + '\',\'Page$' + i + '\')">Page ' + i + '</a><br>';
            }
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="customPager"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example... This shows me that it can be done. I took your sample and adapted it to my gridview and tested with it. and it prints ten lines incrementing 1-10 with Page prepended the links worked well. This of course would not be even close to handling 396 pages (or practical) but gives me hope and somewhere to consider. I'm not proficient with JS so I'll poke around and see what I can find that works in the vein that might do the trick.  Thanks!